# Modify "New" Object Layout through Lookup

Tags: lookup, page-layout, create-records

When using a Lookup field, you can create a new object utilizing the "New" button.

[image: New Button]

My first question, what is this functionality called officially by Salesforce? Can you turn it off?

Secondly, when utilizing this functionality, what layout is displayed and is it editable? See screenshot below.

[image: Lookup]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jesse, thats quick create in action.

---

Just for completeness for other users:

Roger Mitchell answered on Twitter as well: https://twitter.com/RogerMitchell/status/412985773496221696

it's called Quick Create. Can toggle from User Interface in Setup. Layout is not editable. Make your own http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/

Comment: Quick create, snakes and spiders must all be killed dead.

Comment: To be honest, this is one area I haven't had to delve into much as a developer. Sounds like it is lacking from a few quick Google searches I have done. I'll mark this as the correct answer in a few minutes when it allows me to. Thanks all!

Comment: @KevinP I generally disagree with the snakes and spiders (what'd they ever do to YOU?), but Quick Create isn't functional in virtually any organization that has performed any customization at all, so I definitely agree there.

Comment: @sfdcfox - was bitten by brown recluse between shoulder blades as kid. in ruby: kill_with_fire if critter.leg_count < 1 or critter.leg_count > 4